# Python Index is out of bounds

Tags: python, indexoutofboundsexception

I am cleaning up data in a .txt file. I use 3 different .txt. files to analyze and clean up three different constructs. The .txt files all have 10 respondents, the first and the last have 17 answers per respondent. The middle one has 16 answers per respondent. The problem I'm facing right now is that the first and last work, but the middle one with 16 questions has problems with the index. All three pieces of code look almost identical.

The error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 161, in <module>
    itemF = dataF[row,column]
IndexError: index 16 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 16
```

Sample input:

```
['N.v.t.', '0', '1', '2', '1', 'N.v.t.', '0', '0', '2', '0', '0', '3', '2', '3', '1', '1']
['N.v.t.', '1', 'N.v.t.', '0', '0', 'N.v.t.', '2', '0', 'N.v.t.', '1', '0', '1', '1', '2', '0', '1']
['N.v.t.', '0', 'N.v.t.', '0', '0', 'N.v.t.', '0', '0', 'N.v.t.', '0', '0', '3', '0', '3', '0', '0']
['2', '2', 'N.v.t.', '1', '3', '1', '2', '1', '1', '3', '2', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3']
['1', '2', 'N.v.t.', '0', '0', 'N.v.t.', '2', '2', '0', '2', '1', '2', '2', '3', '1', '2']
['N.v.t.', '0', 'N.v.t.', '1', '0', 'N.v.t.', '1', '2', 'N.v.t.', '1', '0', '3', '1', '3', '2', '2']
['0', '3', 'N.v.t.', '0', '2', '3', '2', '1', '3', '2', '2', '2', '2', '3', '0', '1']
['1', '3', 'N.v.t.', '0', '2', 'N.v.t.', '0', '2', 'N.v.t.', '0', '1', '1', '0', '2', '2', '1']
['1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '0', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '1']
['1', '2', 'N.v.t.', '0', '2', 'N.v.t.', '1', '3', '2', '2', '1', '3', '2', '2', '2', '2']
```

The code:

```
import numpy
dataF = numpy.loadtxt("answersFEAR.txt", dtype = str, delimiter = ", ")
shapeF = dataF.shape
(shapeF[0] == 5)
print(dataF)
for i in range(0, shape[0]):
    str1 = dataF[i, 0]
    str2 = dataF[i, -1]
    dataF[i, 0] = str1.replace('[', '')
    dataF[i, -1] = str2.replace(']', '')
for column in range(0,shape[1]):
 for row in range(0, shape[0]):
   itemF = dataF[row,column]
   dataF[rij,kolom] = itemF.replace("'", '')
dataF[dataF == 'N.v.t.'] = numpy.nan
print("DATA FEAR")
print(dataD)
scoresF = dataF[:,1:17]
scoresF = scoresF.astype(float)
average_score_fear = numpy.nanmean(scoresF, axis = 1)
print("")
print("AVERAGE SCORE FEAR")
print(average_score_fear)
```

The expected outcome should look like this (this is just one result):

```
["['1'" "'2'" "'2'" "'2'" "'3'" "'3'" "'0'" "'2'" "'2'" "'2'" "'2'" "'2'" '2'" "'2'" "'2'" "'1']"] 
DATA FEAR
[['1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '0', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '1']]
AVERAGE SCORE FEAR
```

Comment: something is *very* wrong with your indentation. Please fix that so we can see what the problems actually are

Comment: can you add some sample input and expected o/p.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "The .txt files all have 10 respondents, the first and the last have 17 answers per respondent. The middle one has 16 answers per respondent." Numpy arrays are forced to be rectangular, and will not properly store data like that. Please read [ask] and [mre], and show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message that corresponds to the code example. This one clearly does not; `itemD = dataF[row,column]` does not appear anywhere in the code shown.